# Drupal 8 Custom Cron Task

Tags: drupal-8

I have a module, it is very simple with a single `Controller`.

I need the code in this Controller executed on a cron, but the docs seem lacking when adding your own tasks to Drupal's Cron.

I have found references to `hook_cron()` but nothing concrete that shows me where this should go in my module.

The code that is in the Controller can be moved, it is only there so I can test it and execute it at a route.

How do I run custom code in a module using a cron? This can be using Drupal's pseudo cron or using an actual cron. Either is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have found references to hook_cron() but nothing concrete that shows me where this should go in my module.

If your module is called `foo` then a hook means you need to have a function called `foo_cron` somewhere in your `foo.module` file. Order of functions in a PHP file doesn't matter.